# Unable to see the graph, despite using .show() function

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a pandas dataframe, with multiple columns and thousands of rows.

I'm creating a set of graphs that will show diurnal profiles computed by month, from pandas dataframe.

```
                       NO          NO2       NOx    CO           Ozone
From Date                   
2018-12-30 00:00:00 5.856666    39.208341   28.97   331.280881  19.778900
2018-12-30 01:00:00 4.050059    16.262145   13.53   454.031703  25.075286
2018-12-30 02:00:00 4.057806    15.293990   12.96   466.502681  24.825294
2018-12-30 03:00:00 3.835476    13.526193   11.71   446.526784  25.033312
2018-12-30 04:00:00 4.230690    11.251531   10.70   355.638469  25.748796
```

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib
from matplotlib import dates as d
import datetime as dt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
```

```
dataframe['Month'] = dataframe.index.map(lambda x: x.strftime("%m"))
dataframe['Time'] = dataframe.index.map(lambda x: x.strftime("%H:%M"))
for month in dataframe['Month'].unique():
    df = dataframe.loc[dataframe['Month'] == month]

    df = df.groupby('Time').describe()

    ax.plot(df.index, df['Ozone']['mean'], linewidth=2.0, label = month)
    
ax.legend()
ticks = ax.get_xticks()
ax.set_xticks(np.linspace(ticks[0], d.date2num(d.num2date(ticks[-1]) + dt.timedelta(hours=3)), 5))
ax.set_xticks(np.linspace(ticks[0], d.date2num(d.num2date(ticks[-1]) + dt.timedelta(hours=3)), 25), minor=True)
plt.show()
```

I am unable to see any plot despite the code successfully compiling and executing, what could be the problem?

Comment: How did the `'Month'` and `'Time'` columns get created?  If you don't give us code we can run, then few people will be able to help you.

Comment: Apologies. I've corrected the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Next time you put a non-trivial data frame on a question provide a code to create it in python, more people will be likely to help you with your problem instead of recreating your data. Also, not all imports were necessary for this snippet.

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

dataframe = pd.DataFrame( 
    columns = ['From Date',   'NO',          'NO2',       'NOx',    'CO',           'Ozone'],           
    data = [
        ['2018-12-30 00:00:00', 5.856666,    39.208341,   28.97,   331.280881,  19.778900],
        ['2018-12-30 01:00:00', 4.050059,    16.262145,   13.53,   454.031703,  25.075286],
        ['2018-12-30 02:00:00', 4.057806,    15.293990,   12.96,   466.502681,  24.825294],
        ['2018-12-30 03:00:00', 3.835476,    13.526193,   11.71,   446.526784,  25.033312],
        ['2018-12-30 04:00:00', 4.230690,    11.251531,   10.70,   355.638469,  25.748796]
    ]
)
dataframe['From Date'] = pd.to_datetime(dataframe['From Date'])
dataframe = dataframe.set_index('From Date')
```

After performing the following code (missing `ax` object) I received the following graph.

```py
dataframe['Month'] = dataframe.index.map(lambda x: x.strftime("%m"))
dataframe['Time'] = dataframe.index.map(lambda x: x.strftime("%H:%M"))
#I've added this line too
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1)
for month in dataframe['Month'].unique():
    df = dataframe.loc[dataframe['Month'] == month]
    df = df.groupby('Time').describe()
    ax.plot(df.index, df['Ozone']['mean'], linewidth=2.0, label = month)
    
ax.legend()
ticks = ax.get_xticks()
ax.set_xticks(np.linspace(ticks[0], d.date2num(d.num2date(ticks[-1]) + dt.timedelta(hours=3)), 5))
ax.set_xticks(np.linspace(ticks[0], d.date2num(d.num2date(ticks[-1]) + dt.timedelta(hours=3)), 25), minor=True)
plt.show()
```

[image]

This is my matplotlib version:

```py
import matplotlib
matplotlib.__version__
'3.4.1'
```

If this code is not working for you, try to upgrade matplotlib to the newer version and post the results if it is still not working.

Comment: Hey, so this worked for me. Thanks! and sorry for the inconvenience caused.
I just wanted to ask, what command could I use if I have multiple months, for example, December is 12 over here, so how can I plot separately for different months? Could this be done by changing any statement in the for loop?

Comment: The graph I'm getting, is quite convoluted and tough to understand, hence is there any way I can separate the various graph lines into different plots?

Comment: That is another question, could you post another question or do the research on using `plt` with multiple lines.